# Pagination and sorting large amount of data

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, pagination

I am wondering how to properly implement sorting and pagination mechanism in any application using tabular display of some data. Let's assume we have some entity with id and description. There are many instances of them in the database. I would like to sort alphabetically  by description. But I want to have result fast. Is this possible to do without getting from database all of the records, sorting them and then displaying only some part of them? What is the best (from performance point of view) approach to this problem?

My question is rather hypothetical and does not pertain to any particular language or framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in two passes

The first one returns only the `id`s of the entity sorted by whatever criteria. The list of `id`s is saved in memory.

The second one takes one page, i.e. a sublist of `id`s and fetches the whole entities from the database for presentation.

Comment: Assuming there are billions of IDs, or more, this could take a while. I assume the idea behind the question is to avoid loading (even just some part of) all records.

Comment: Storing billions of IDs in a single database and having them queried efficiently is not going to be an easy task. Billions of records may be better stored in several databases and then the computation can be done in parallel. It seems that the question was referring to a single database.

Comment: Yes. It refers to a single database. In fact, Boris, your solution convinced me :)